# How do I automatically make after cmake finished generating the files

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, cmake, automation

I am currently trying to set up an "automatic build process" on mac for my C++ "Hello World Project" that uses Cmake & visual studio code.

My current workflow to build in terminal or with vscode's tasks.json is the following, and I find them very tedious to do.

1. cmake ... (to generate the cmake & make files inside the build folder)
2. make (inside the build folder to create the application's executable)
3. ./{application's executable}

Thus, I have have looked into the following

1. vs code's prelaunch task
2. cmake's add_custom_commands
3. custom bash script
4. python scripts

But I'm a bit lost with the above try-outs, and need some helps. My end goal is to automatically build and run the updated code by either pressing F5 in vscode or calling a custom ./{command} in terminal.

Comment: Is your project changing its layout a lot? Files getting added and removed? Dependencies change? If not, there is no reason to run cmake before running make again.

Comment: We are using a makefile that calls cmake if the destination build directory does not exist yet, afterwards calls make to actually compile/link. Then you just need to type `make`.

Comment: The layout wont change alot, but files could be added & removed few times.

Comment: You know you can string together multiple command in the terminal? `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3`. It will even be the case that if an earlier command fails then the later commands won't run. Then you can use the up arrow key to recall this cmmand from the command history and two keystrokes will do your entire build.

Comment: Do you have the CMake Tools extension installed? It does make building a lot easier.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your project layout is changing or not.  Any change to any cmake file will cause make to automatically re-run cmake, and any change to any other file will cause its dependencies to be re-generated.  In short, you only ever need to run cmake one time, when you first check out the project (or if you clean up/delete all the makefiles).  After that you can just run make all the time and it will do the right things.

Comment: @john I didn't know that, thank you very much :)

Comment: @ Michael Surette I have installed the Cmake & Cmake Tools extension, but I didn't know how to bind that extension's build process with the "launch task" in vscode >.<

Comment: @MadScientist oh~ just to re-confirm: Only when I change the folder structure, or add/remove files, I need to edit and run cmake to regenerate the makefiles. If I just edit the existing files (without changing the #includes), then all I need to do is "make", correct?.  Thank you all in advance!

Comment: If you add/remove files or change the folder structure, you will have to edit one or more of the cmake files (CMakeLists.txt) to reflect that change.  When you do that, then run make (not cmake!) the makefiles will notice that you changed the cmake files, they will run cmake for you so you don't have to do it, then they will re-invoke make with the new makefiles generated by running cmake.  It's very rare that you need to run cmake again by hand for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Combining everyone's suggestions, the approach I took is to create a task.json that contains the following command-flow

- cmd1: cmake to generate the makefiles & cmake files to a build folder
- cmd2: make -j 8 to build with multiple cores
- cmd1 && cmd2

Then I made two different launches in launch.json. The major difference between them is the prelauch task. One of them is "cmd1&&cmd2", and another one is only "cmd2". That way I can have two hotkeys like F5 and F7 for me to choose. If the folder structure & files weren't added or removed I will hit F7 which only calls the "cmd2" pre-launch task, otherwise F5.

I think a better approach is to either write a bash script or dig deeper in cmakelist.txt which I believe it has the "if statements" that determine when should it do "cmd1 &&cmd2" or just "cmd2" alone. That way, I don't need two hotkeys to build/debug and run in vscode (don't know if it is possible, I haven't try yet.)

If anyone has done it, please comment below or create a new answer.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
cmake --build
```

after the first time you configured the build. Optional parameters include the build directory and targets to build.

Comment: cmake 3.20 emits ` CMake Error: Unknown argument: --build`